# kendo knockout combobox event issue

Tags: events, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

html part

```
<input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { dataTextField: 'FirstName', dataValueField: 'PersonID',  data: AllUsers,template: '<span>#= data.FirstName # #= data.LastName # </span>',  value: SelectedUserID, 
change: UserSelectionChanged}" />
```

event handler inside model

```
var self= this;...    
self.UserSelectionChanged = function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: defaultUri + '/Home/GetUserTasks',
            data: JSON.stringify({ PersonID: self.SelectedUserID() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (o) {
                self.SelectedUserTask(null);
                self.SelectedUserTask(o);
                //RRM: Added this line below so that whenever user dropdown is changed or refresh button is clicked in AssignedTo the first task of that particular user is Selected.
                self.selectTask(o[0]);

            }
        });
    };
```

here the event is being called but the data in `self` is not there. The event doesn't seems to be bind well with knockout.
how to properly bind the `ko` event in the `kendo combobox` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of registring to the change event, I'd subscribe to `SelectedUserID`:

```
var self= this;
...
self.SelectedUserID.subscribe(function(selectedUserId) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: defaultUri + '/Home/GetUserTasks',
        data: JSON.stringify({ PersonID: selectedUserId }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (o) {
            self.SelectedUserTask(null);
            self.SelectedUserTask(o);
            //RRM: Added this line below so that whenever user dropdown is changed or refresh button is clicked in AssignedTo the first task of that particular user is Selected.
            self.selectTask(o[0]);

        }
    });
});
```

This way it doesn't matter when or how the `SelectedUserID` is being changed.

Answer (score 0):

As sroes wrote subscribing to the observable is the best choice here.

In cases where you have to bind to the kendo event then you can do this:

```
data-bind="... change: UserSelectionChanged(), ...."
```

Notice the function call parenthesis at the end ^

Now you function has to be like this:

```
this.UserSelectionChanged = function () {
    var self = this;

    return function(e) {
        $.ajax({ 
            self.blah ...
        });
    }
}
```

Now you have created a closure and you can access your view model using *self* but you also have the original Telerik event args inside *e* like e.dataItem etc.

So now you are unstoppable, you can do everything!